# Angular 2 Observable<number>

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I am doing a countdown timer in AngularJS 2 that start from n= 60 sec (i.e. hh: min: sec)

For that I have the following:

```
countDown: Observable<number>;
count = 60;

constructor() { 
this.countDown = Observable.timer(0,1000)
.take(this.count)
.map(()=> --this.count);
```

}

HTML

```
<h2>{{ countDown/(60*60)}} : {{countDown/60}} : {{countDown%60}}</h4>
```

The output I am getting is "NaN : NaN : NaN" but when I used `<h2>{{ countDown}}</h2>` I am getting correct countDown but not in a way I want

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: so.. what is the question? and where is `countDown`set?

Comment: @Suraj Rao sorry for the confusion i have updated the problem pls have a look again

Comment: @M. Oğuz Özcan  pls have a look again

Comment: as I asked where is countDown set and declared?

Comment: ops i have declared pls have a look again

Comment: Is `counter` also missing?

Comment: @stealththeninja pls have a look again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to perform arithmetic operations with an `Observable` object instead of a number. Use async pipe and save it in [a local html reference](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#storing-conditional-result-in-a-variable).

```
<h2 *ngIf="countDown | async as countValue">{{ countValue/(60*60)}} : {{countValue/60}} : {{countValue%60}}</h2>
```

Comment: not working, counter is not empty it has value pls read question

Comment: you have changed the code completely now..and there seems to be a syntax issue in your constructor.

Comment: it an object instant of number that point i get but not able to typecast

Comment: Your code is giving syntax error. Please post a correct code.

Comment: pls have a look again

Comment: check updated answer.. you are using latest angular?

Comment: still same ans , @angular/cli: 1.4.7 , node: 6.10.3

Comment: not cli version.. your angular version in package.json

Comment: @Mastityem if the answer provided helped you, please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) which marks question as solved :)